# Почему программа срабатывает именно так?

Tags: java

Учу `java` по книге Шилдта - в книге приведена программка-пример:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Для остановки нажмите клавишу s");
        for (i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++)
            System.out.println("Введите верную букву");
    }
}
```

Программа просит в консоли ввести букву `s`. Если вводишь `s`, то она завершает работу, а если вводишь неверную букву то в консоли 2 раза выводится надпись: `Введите верную букву` `Введите верную букву`.

Вот и вопрос - а почему она 2 раза выводится?, а не один или не бесконечно, так как инкремент то неограничен каким-либо условием типа `i<5`? И значение `i` меняю на любое другое и программа все равно работает. Почему - я не понимаю?

Буду благодарен если популярно по шагам объясните что и как тут работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это связано с тем , что программа читает по символьно. То есть 1 раз она читает введенный символ а потом просит его ввести. Если ввести 4 символа то 5 раз будет обрабатываться цикл for.Таким образом он будет высвечивать при вводе n числа символов, будет высвечиваться n+1 строк. Так как цикл будет читать каждый новый символ в новом "круге" цикла.

Comment: Не совсем понял... А какой самый первый символ читает программа?

Comment: Смотрите сначала программа читает 1 символ, и  это считается как 1 круг цикла и поэтому она выводит строку введите символ, а потом программа видит что этот символ не "s" и еще раз просит ввести символ и это уже 2 круг цикла.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)))